# Criteria Api or @Query annotation with Spel for advanced search?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm building an advanced search function for which I'm considering to use Spring Expression Lanugage with `@Query` (JPQL/HQL) or the Criteria API. I don't want to use Query DSL. What do you think, which is better? What are the limits of those?

Answer (score 1):

HQLs are much easier to read, easier to debug whereas Criteria queries are used for building dynamic queries where a lot of the behavior is determined at runtime. So HQL is preferred if you know exactly what you want.

However, On a search functionality, where user can enter any of 1 to 40 items and we don't know what they will be searching for. So, It will be very easy to append more to the criteria.